# Microstates in phase space

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Recently i am studying Statistical mechanics and reading about the Boltzman hypothesis about entropy
$$S = k \,ln\,\Omega(E)$$
where it says $\Omega(E)$ is total no. of microstates , the available volume  in phase space . Now if i consider an ideal gas confined in a volume V then the Total no. of microstate is $$ \Omega\,=\,\frac{V}{h^3}\int dp_1\,dp_2\,dp_3...dp_{3N}$$

And as for free particles $E\,=\,\frac{p^2}{2m}$ so if i write the integration in momentum space in spherical polar coordinate then Radius of the sphere is $p\,=\,\sqrt{2mE}$

[image]

Now the total no. of microstates $\Omega(E)$ is no. of microstates from energy 0 to E. And we use this to calculate Entropy S.
Now my question is in microcanonical ensemble if i say the system is in Energy E to E+$\Delta$E then the total no. of available microstate is $$ \Delta\Omega\,=\,\Omega(E+\Delta E)-\Omega(E)$$
the microstates which are in the hyper shell, but while writing entropy we use total no. of microstate $\Omega(E)$ which is actually total no. of microstate from energy o to E not from E to E+$\Delta$E. 
So apparently we will get wrong answer , we should calculate 
$$ S\,=\,k\,ln(\Delta \Omega)\,=\, k\,ln\,(\Omega(E+\Delta E)-\Omega(E))$$

So why we use total no. of microstate from energy 0 to E to calculate Entropy although the system can have energy only from E to E+$\Delta$E  ?

Comment: Where is your fixed energy  E in your integral for omega?

Comment: Here at formula 18 https://theory.physics.manchester.ac.uk/~xian/thermal/chap3.pdf the E enters in  delta function.  as far as I can tell the limits of intergration for dp are from -infinity to +infinity, it is the delta function that restrains the values.